# How do I exit the Meteor development server on Mac (CTRL-C equivalent)?

Tags: node.js, meteor

I have a project in Meteor that I started in Windows but have now migrated over to OS X.  In Windows, I was always able to stop running the project locally simply by using CTRL-C.  This doesn't seem to do anything in the terminal in OS X, it just brings up a new command line.

When I type `meteor reset`, I get the following:

```
reset: Meteor is running.
This command does not work while Meteor is running your application. Exit the running Meteor development server.
```

I looked at `meteor --help` but no luck there.  I also saw a post recommending I go into Activity Monitor and shut down any node processes (which didn't help) but there has to be a way to do this directly from the terminal.

I'm stuck and can't reload the app, because I can't shut down the previous one.  Thanks.

Comment: I've always been able to stop meteor with ctrl-c on the Mac.

Comment: Strange.  CTRL-C just brings up a new command line, nothing happens.

Comment: what do you mean about `brings up a new command line`?

Comment: I'm working in Webstorm.  My terminal's command line shows my computer's name, my project name and ends in $.  When I type CTRL-c, it just adds the same command line below it.  Nothing executes.

Comment: CTRL-C does get me back to the command line but when I try to run `meteor reset`, it says `reset: Meteor is running.`  How do I completely shut it down so I can reset the local db?

Comment: ok, so you run the command in the command window of Webstorm, am I correct?

Comment: Correct.  I run `meteor` from the command line in the Webstorm terminal.  In the past, I've been able ti run CTRL-C in the same terminal, which then allows me to run `meteor reset` but now it won't work. I did something right using my computer's terminal which properly shut down the Meteor server, but now I can't figure out what it was.  Apologies, very new at this

Comment: then you should stick with webstorm in order to start/stop meteor. Ctrl+C does not help here. IDE will have their own way to start/stop the server and you cannot use this way to start the server and then use the other way to stop it. I don't use webstorm thus cannot give any advise for this. Basically, i prefer `Sublime` and terminal from Mac. Simple and less hassled :D

Comment: in webstorm click the red cross icon to terminate the process

Comment: It's because `mongod` is not stopped when you type `ctrl + c`. But I don't know why, I have the same issue on OSX. No problem on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 15):

Use this code to kill the meteor process:

```
kill `ps ax | grep '[m]eteor' | awk '{print $1}'`
```

Comment: I copied that line into the terminal (in Webstorm) and it returned the following:
`kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]`
I'm pretty new to this, did I miss a step?  Surprised it would be so much easier in Windows.

Comment: Sorry. That would have worked in Linux. Try the new code above instead.

Comment: Delete original post to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

in Webstorm, click the red cross icon on the left side bar to close the terminal session.

Comment: Same issue when I reopen, Meteor is still running.

Comment: what about you run Meteor with the RUN command instead within WebStorm. this is the proper way to run Meteor in WebStorm. Set a Configuration (drop down next to the green RUN arrow on top right of your window) and then + to set a new config, choose Meteor as the engine, and set your work directory